# What solutions are there to $R(1/x) = x^kR(x)$?

Tags: functions, polynomials

What solutions are there to the functional equation
$R(1/x) = x^kR(x)$,
where $k$ is a non-negative integer?

This is a generalization of the earlier question
[Functional equation: $R(1/x)/x^2 = R(x) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449070/functional-equation-r1-x-x2-rx/449143#449143)
 which had $k=2$.

A more general question is this:

What solutions are there to the functional equation
$p(x)R(1/x) = q(x)R(x)$,
where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are pre-specified polynomials?

I have only looked at the first equation,
though my technique below might be a starting point
for the second question.

Here is what I have done so far.

I will look for solutions 
to $R(1/x) = x^kR(x)$
of the form $R(x) = A(x)/B(x)$,
where $A$ and $B$ are  relatively prime polynomials
of respective degrees $n$ and $m$,

Some definitions:

If $C(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ (so $C(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$), $[x^i]C(x)$ is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $C(x)$ (i.e., $[x^i]C(x) = c_i$), $deg(C(x)$ is the largest $i$ such that $[x^i]C(x)$ is non-zero, $codeg(C(x))$ is the smallest $i$ such that $[x^i]C(x)$ is non-zero, $\rho(C(x))$ is the reciprocal polynomial of $C(x)$ so that $\rho(C(x)) = x^n C(1/x) = \sum_{i=0}^n [x^i]C(x) x^{n-i} = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^{n-i}$.

A polynomial $C(x)$ is $symmetric$ if $C(x) = \rho(C(x))$.

Suppose $R(x) = A(x)/B(x)$ where $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are  relatively prime polynomials of degrees $n$ and $m$, respectively. Let $\rho(A(x)) = a(x)$ and $\rho(B(x)) = b(x)$, so that $a(x) = x^nA(1/x)$ and $b(x) = x^mB(1/x)$. Let $u = deg(a(x))$ and $v = deg(b(x))$.

We have $R(1/x)= A(1/x)/B(1/x)= (a(x)x^{-n})/(b(x)x^{-m})= x^{m-n}a(x)/b(x)$, so that $x^{m-n}a(x)/b(x) = x^k A(x)/B(x)$ or $x^ma(x)B(x) = x^{n+k}A(x)b(x)$.

The degree of the left side is $m+u+m = 2m+u$ and the degree of the right side is $n+k+n+v = 2n+k+v$, so $2m+u=2n+k+v$.

I now look at various possibilities for $A(x)$ and $B(x)$.

If the degrees of $a(x)$
and $b(x)$ are the same
as $A$ and $B$, respectively,
(i.e., the constant terms of $A$ and $B$ are non-zero),
then $u=n$ and $v=m$,
so that $2m+n=2n+k+m$
or $m = n+k$.
This means that $a(x)B(x) = A(x)b(x)$.
Since $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are relatively prime,
so are $a(x)$ and $b(x)$,
so that $a(x) = A(x)$ and $b(x) = B(x)$
which means that $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are symmetric.

Conversely, if $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are symmetric
and $deg(B(x)) = k+deg(A(x))$,
it is easy to verify that
$R(x)=A(x)/B(x)$ satisfies 
$R(1/x) = x^kR(x)$.

As a special case,
if $B(x)$ is symmetric with degree $k$,
then $1/B(x)$ satisfies the equation
(i.e., $A(x) = 1$).

Suppose $A(x) = x^n$, so that $a(x) = 1$ and $u = 0$.
The condition $2m+u=2n+k+v$
becomes $2m=2n+k+v$
(or $v = 2m-2n-k$)
and $x^ma(x)B(x) = x^{n+k}A(x)b(x)$
becomes $x^mB(x) = x^{2n+k}b(x)$.
Since $v \le m$, 
$2m=2n+k+v \le 2n+k+m$ or $m \le 2n+k$.
so $B(x) = x^{2n+k-m}b(x)$.
Therefore the part of $B(x)$ 
with the low-order zero coefficients removed
is symmetric. The converse also holds.

If $B(x) = x^m$, so $b(x) = 1$ and $v=0$,
$2m+u=2n+k$ 
and $x^ma(x)B(x) = x^{n+k}A(x)b(x)$ 
becomes $x^{2m}a(x) = x^{2n+k}A(x)$
or $x^{2m-2n-k}a(x) = A(x)$. 
Therefore, as with $B(x)$, above, 
the part of $A(x)$ 
with the low-order zero coefficients removed 
is symmetric. 
The converse also holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $R(x)=x^nf(x)$ ,

Then $R\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=x^{-n}f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$\therefore x^{-n}f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=x^{n+k}f(x)$

Choose $-n=n+k\Rightarrow n=-\dfrac{k}{2}$ , the functional equation becomes $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=f(x)$

In fact this functional equation belongs to the form of http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/fe/fe1120.pdf.

$f(x)=C\left(x~,\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ , where $C(u,v)$ is any symmetric function.

$\therefore R(x)=x^{-\frac{k}{2}}C\left(x~,\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$ , where $C(u,v)$ is any symmetric function.

Comment: I accepted your answer, even though your reference does not prove the result. Do you know of a proof?

Comment: @martycohen Tha page provides a reference, does it not?